# Conditional Seque (Parse and Swift)

Tags: swift, parse-platform, segue

I'm trying to do a conditional segue from one view controller to the other based on whether or not a user is successfully signed up.  I am using the Parse framework in this project.  When the button is clicked using new login data that should not return an error, the app crashes.  When the button is clicked using login data that already exists, an error should be returned, and the app crashes.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class SignUpController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var emailField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var passField: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func submitButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var user = PFUser()
    user.username = emailField.text
    user.password = passField.text

    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SignIn", sender: self)

        } else {

            println("failure")

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error/crash messages that you're getting?

Comment: It ended up being a really stupid problem, I had a breakpoint that was messing it up.  I'm really new to iOS development.